# Prevent networkmanager to disable an interface if dhcp timeout when mixed dhcp and fixe ip configuration

Tags: networking, debian, ip, dhcp, networkmanager

I need to find a way for a computer to have both a fixed ip address AND have be a dhcp client on the same interface. So far it works great, I am using Debian 11 and NetworkManager.

The problem, is that if the dhcp is not available, after a timeout, as the dhcp didn't send an ip to use, then networkmanager is disabling the interface, as well as the fixed ip.

Is there a way to prevent it ? let networkmanager ask for dhcp indefinitely, or at least make it not disabling the interface as there is a fixed ip set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this command :

```
nmcli connection modify conname ipv4.dhcp-timeout infinity
```

And it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Personally, I consider needing to change this setting a bug. For a discussion on this see: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-dhcp-static-ip-on-a-wired-connection/14121/3